# Multiple inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, multiple-inheritance

Here's some question about oop in js (questions in the code below).

```
<html>
    <script>
    function A(){
      a = 'a - private FROM A()';
      this.a = 'a - public FROM A()';
      this.get_a = function(){
        return a;
      }
    }

    function B(){
      this.b = 'b - private FROM B()';
      this.a = 'a - public FROM B() ';
    }

    C.prototype = new A();
    C.prototype = new B();
    C.prototype.constructor = C;
    function C() {
      A.call(this);
      B.call(this);
    }

    var c = new C();

    //I've read paper about oop in Javacscript but they never talk 
    //(the ones have read of course) about multiple inheritance, any 
    //links to such a paper?

    alert(c.a);
    alert(c.b);
    alert(c.get_a());

    //but

    //Why the hell is variable a from A() now in the Global object?
    //Look like C.prototype = new A(); is causing it.

    alert(a);

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess I should clarify my question : What are the drawback of multi-inheritance in js?  And why variable a is in global scope?

Comment: Then put that in the question - use the edit button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variable `a` with the `var` statement in order to make it local to the function.

```
function A(){
  var a = 'a - private FROM A()';
  this.a = 'a - public FROM A()';
  this.get_a = function(){
    return a;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
C.prototype = new A();
C.prototype = new B();
```

Multiple inheritence isn't supported in javascript. All you've done is make C inherit from B instead of A.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. When you do this

```
C.prototype = new A();
C.prototype = new B();
```

You are merely changing the object that `prototype` points to. So C used to inherit from A, but now it inherits from B.

You can fake multiple inheritance

```
C.prototype = new A();

for (var i in B.prototype)
  if (B.prototype.hasOwnProperty(i))
    C.prototype[i] = B.prototype[i];
```

Now you'd have the properties/methods from both A and B, but you don't really have inheritance, since any changes to the `prototype` object of B will not propagate to C.